# Calculate correlation for all country pairs over multiple years in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, correlation

I’m currently facing the following issue: Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422786/calculate-correlation-between-two-countries-using-matching-subclasses-in-r), **I need to calculate the correlation between nations (Value.x and Value.y) for multiple countries for multiple years**.  **What is the best way to achieve that?**

An expected output should be something like this (for all country pairs and all years). Thus, all correlation results are stored in a table/dataframe.

```
correlation country_x     country_y       Time

0.787812    Germany     United States   2000
```

The first 100 rows of my dataset look like this:

```
structure(list(LOCATION.x = c("AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS"), Country.x = c("Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia"), IPC = c("A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", "A01B", 
"A01B", "A01B", "A01B"), Time = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), Value.x = c(3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 3.3333, 
3.3333, 3.3333, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 
4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 
4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 
4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 
4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 
4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 4.2143, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 
1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944, 
1.1944, 1.1944, 1.1944), LOCATION.y = c("AUS", "AUT", "BEL", 
"CAN", "CZE", "DNK", "FIN", "FRA", "DEU", "GRC", "HUN", "ISL", 
"IRL", "ITA", "JPN", "KOR", "LUX", "MEX", "NLD", "NZL", "NOR", 
"POL", "PRT", "SVK", "ESP", "SWE", "CHE", "TUR", "GBR", "USA", 
"BRA", "CHL", "CHN", "COL", "CRI", "EST", "IND", "IDN", "ISR", 
"LVA", "LTU", "SVN", "ZAF", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN", "CZE", 
"DNK", "FIN", "FRA", "DEU", "GRC", "HUN", "ISL", "IRL", "ITA", 
"JPN", "KOR", "LUX", "MEX", "NLD", "NZL", "NOR", "POL", "PRT", 
"SVK", "ESP", "SWE", "CHE", "TUR", "GBR", "USA", "BRA", "CHL", 
"CHN", "COL", "CRI", "EST", "IND", "IDN", "ISR", "LVA", "LTU", 
"SVN", "ZAF", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN", "CZE", "DNK", "FIN", 
"FRA", "DEU", "GRC", "HUN", "ISL", "IRL", "ITA"), Country.y = c("Australia", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"Ireland", "Italy", "Japan", "Korea", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
"Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", 
"Slovak Republic", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", 
"United Kingdom", "United States", "Brazil", "Chile", "China", 
"Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Estonia", "India", "Indonesia", "Israel", 
"Latvia", "Lithuania", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"Ireland", "Italy", "Japan", "Korea", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
"Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", 
"Slovak Republic", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", 
"United Kingdom", "United States", "Brazil", "Chile", "China", 
"Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Estonia", "India", "Indonesia", "Israel", 
"Latvia", "Lithuania", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"Ireland", "Italy"), Value.y = c(3.3333, 0, 0, 0.6667, 0, 1.1429, 
0.7333, 7.0667, 3.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, 0.4762, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2.5, 13.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4.2143, 0.3333, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2.5, 5.0833, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.4167, 0.5667, 0, 0, 0.5, 1.6278, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2.45, 9.1742, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.1, 1.1944, 0.5, 0.5, 2.3409, 0.0909, 0, 0.6, 8, 6.0286, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.5)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    IPC = "A01B", .rows = structure(list(1:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In response to the comments, I added this example dataset for didactic purposes. It should work with the code provided by @r2evans. (It assumes that the listed countries have only two sub dimensions A01B and A01C for the years 2000 and 2001.)

```
structure(list(LOCATION.x = c("AUS", "AUS", "USA", "USA", "AUS", 
"AUS", "USA", "USA"), Country.x = c("Australia", "Australia", 
"United States", "United States", "Australia", "Australia", "United States", 
"United States"), IPC = c("A01B", "A01C", "A01B", "A01C", "A01B", 
"A01C", "A01B", "A01C"), Time = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001), Value.x = c(7, 42, 92, 1, 70, 87, 88, 3), 
    LOCATION.y = c("DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", 
    "DEU", "DEU"), Country.y = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
    "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"), Value.y = c(97, 
    85, 25, 14, 15, 97, 97, 52)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can see, each combination of `Country.x` and `Country.y` only has one unique x and y value per year. How would you expect to calculate a correlation from these single data points? Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: @Rory S: I believe your interpretation is correct. I uploaded only a limited dataset due to space limitations. I will revise it then to make things clearer. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do a simple `summarize` for that,

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(Country.x, Country.y) %>%
  summarize(corr = cor(Value.x, Value.y)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))
# Warning in cor(Value.x, Value.y) : the standard deviation is zero
##### repeated 21 times
# # A tibble: 21 x 3
# # Groups:   Country.x [1]
#    Country.x Country.y        corr
#    <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
#  1 Australia Australia       1    
#  2 Australia Austria        -0.539
#  3 Australia Belgium        -0.959
#  4 Australia Canada         -1.00 
#  5 Australia Czech Republic -0.959
#  6 Australia Denmark         0.931
#  7 Australia Finland         0.911
#  8 Australia France         -0.825
#  9 Australia Germany        -0.550
# 10 Australia India          -1    
# # ... with 11 more rows
```

With more data and wanting to add `Time` to your grouping, then use

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(Time, Country.x, Country.y) %>%
  summarize(corr = cor(Value.x, Value.y))
```

This doesn't work here due to the small sample but should work on your larger data.

Comment: Your suggested code worked perfectly! Many thanks. I will add a second example dataset tomorrow to enable a better understanding of my question and your solution as the first 100 rows are not sufficient for understanding according to the feedback from you and @Rory S.

Comment: As promised, I added another dataset for didactic purposes. It works with your code and acknowledges the **time** dimension.